# How do I add a layer and a feature with one click

Tags: openlayers-2

In Openlayers, I want on a single click on the map for a layer to be added and a feature to be dropped where I click.

```
vectorLayer = new OpenLayers.Layer.Vector("layer", {styleMap: currentStyle,'displayInLayerSwitcher': true});
map.addLayer(vectorLayer);
drawFeature = new OpenLayers.Control.DrawFeature(vectorLayer, OpenLayers.Handler.Point);
map.addControl(drawFeature);
```

I think this should probably be done with events somehow. But every option I try invovles a double click - one to add the layer, and one to add the feature. Anybody know how to solve this crisis? Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Only you need to do is to bind a OnClick event on the map and process what you want:

```
function bindClickButton() {
    OpenLayers.Control.Click = OpenLayers.Class(OpenLayers.Control, {                
        defaultHandlerOptions: {
            'single': true,
            'double': false,
            'pixelTolerance': 0,
            'stopSingle': false,
            'stopDouble': false
        },

        initialize: function(options) {
            this.handlerOptions = OpenLayers.Util.extend(
                {}, this.defaultHandlerOptions
            );
            OpenLayers.Control.prototype.initialize.apply(
                this, arguments
            ); 
            this.handler = new OpenLayers.Handler.Click(
                this, {
                    'click': this.trigger
                }, this.handlerOptions
            );
        }, 

        trigger: function(e) {
            var lonlat = map.getLonLatFromPixel(e.xy);
            lonlat.transform( map.projection,map.displayProjection);
            processMouseClick(lonlat);
        }

    });

    var click = new OpenLayers.Control.Click();
    map.addControl(click);
    click.activate();

}
```

So, create the processMouseClick() to process the click :

```
function processMouseClick(lonlat) {
    // DO_ALL_YOUR_JOB_HERE
}
```

Just ignore my projection transform if not in your case.

Comment: Remember : `var lon = lonlat.lon; var lat = lonlat.lat;`

Comment: In your way, every click on map adds a new layer. Is this what you realy want? Be careful.